# ASP.NET MVC 5 Decouple Identity 2.0 to separate class library

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity-2

Aim is to make decouple the application from Identity. By default the identity code makes a reference to EntityFramework in the main project, which is undesired.

I am able to create a new class library and add reference to `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework` and related assemblies. Problem is that the `AccountController` is tightly coupled to `UserManager` and `ApplicationDbContext` in Identity libraries.

```
public AccountController()
            : this(new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new ApplicationDbContext())))
```

Comment: Then change AccountController. What's the problem?

Comment: Rewrite the entire controller again?

Comment: The entire thing? No, just that part.

Comment: Aseem did you figure out how to decouple the UserManager, SignInManager from the Account Controller?

Comment: @alikuli no I don't remember.. its been a while

Comment: Ok. Thanks for responding. I finally managed it. The ONLY way to decouple SignInManager and UserManager, (and later you find out, IAuthenticationManager) is to use a Dependancy Injection software. I tried Autofac, but it has some sort of built in error for MVC, so I switched to NInject. Works great now. All decoupled.

Comment: @alikuli would you like to share some code? thanks

Comment: Sure. I managed to convert my application from string based user to Guid, and then I even managed to decouple the AccountController. I am working on the ManageController. I will rewrite the string based user, and share that. Give me a day or so.

Comment: I have done step one... separating the models in MVC 5. if you like it and want the next, please like it, I will do another the next step for separating the UserManager and DbContext. Please see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45847391/how-should-i-separate-the-models-in-an-mvc5-website-into-a-different-c-sharp-cla,